# This question seems tricky, can this question be solved with truth tables?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-explanation

**Show that if a condition $P$ is both necessary $(\neg P \Rightarrow\neg Q)$ and
sufficient $(P \Rightarrow Q)$, that this is logically equivalent to $P=Q$.**

I don't understand how to prove this. I tried writing a truth table but in order to solve it, $p$ and $q$ are opposite.  Maybe I'm reading it wrong can someone please explain this question, thanks

Comment: Not very clear... Maybe If $P$ is both [necessary and sufficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency#Definitions) for $Q$, then $P$ and $Q$ are  equivalent. The first part means $(Q \to P)$ while the seocnd means $(P \to Q)$. Thus...

Comment: Hint: to use truth tables, you need to convert the problem to the following: **Prove that $((\neg P \to \neg Q) \wedge ( P \to Q ) )\to (P=Q)$.**

Answer (score 0):

There are Only two cases :
$P$ true or false.

Assume $P$ true. $P$ is a sufficient condition, thus $ Q$ is also true.

If $ P $ is false then as a necessary condition, $ Q$ will be also false.

we conclude that $ P $ and $ Q $ have the same logical value. we say that they are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

(1)
$A \Leftrightarrow B$ is equivalent to 
($A \Rightarrow B$) **and** ($B \Rightarrow A$).

(2) 
$A \Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to 
$(\neg B) \Rightarrow (\neg A)$.

To the OP: for your problem, if you are not allowed to assume (2) above, you might consider generally proving (2) above first.  (2) above simplifies attacking the original problem.